# How do I select between the 1st day of the current month and current day in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, get

I need to select data from MySQL database between the 1st day of the current month and current day.

```
select*from table_name 
where date between "1st day of current month" and "current day"
```

Can someone provide working example of this query?

Comment: possibly reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887509/mysqls-now-1-day

Answer (score 169, accepted):

```
select * from table_name 
where (date between  DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 30 day), interval 1 day) AND CURDATE() )
```

Or better :

```
select * from table_name 
where (date between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )
```

Comment: If `date` is a **datetime** then we had to use DATE(date) to get it to compare correctly.

Comment: I would use curdate() instead of now() to take advantages of indexes (if any)

Comment: possible change `date between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW()` to `date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')`

Comment: The first example works if you subtract `INTERVAL 1 MONTH`.

Comment: Just be careful using BETWEEN and dates without times. It's probably not inclusive depending on the exact query, and the original question doesn't indicate if that is desired. So the clarify of the intent isn't there imo.

Comment: The first example will be wrong when CURDATE equals the start of march

Answer (score 30):

I was looking for a similar query where I needed to use the first day of a month in my query.
The `last_day` function didn't work for me but `DAYOFMONTH` came in handy.

So if anyone is looking for the same issue, the following code returns the date for first day of the current month.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY);
```

Comparing a date column with the first day of the month :

```
select * from table_name where date between 
DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY) and CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Use [`DAY` instead of `DAYOFMONTH`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28966866/632951). Also, use the 2-arity overload of `subdate` instead. It's faster than the 3-arity `date_sub`.

Comment: The caveat with this method is that it breaks if you try to go back to prior months, making it a dangerous piece of code to implement. There are better and more elegant solutions offered here which are more adaptable to extension.

Comment: @Pacerier Both your suggestions will work, but whats the difference??  I prefer `DAYOFMONTH` over `DAY` as it makes clear that i am specifically looking for the Day Of Month & not year / week.  Also how is `subdate` faster than `date_sub` they are practically doing the same calculation

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from table_name 
where `date` between curdate() - dayofmonth(curdate()) + 1
                 and curdate()
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f355/1)

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following query. It has worked great for me in the past.

```
select date(now()) - interval day(now()) day + interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
SET @StartDate = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL (DAY(NOW())-1) DAY);
SET @EndDate = ADDDATE(CURDATE(),1);
select * from table where (date >= @StartDate and date < @EndDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found myself here after needing this same query for some Business Intelligence Queries I'm running on an e-commerce store. I wanted to add my solution as it may be helpful to others.

```
set @firstOfLastLastMonth = DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)))-1 DAY);
set @lastOfLastLastMonth = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH));
set @firstOfLastMonth = DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)))-1 DAY);
set @lastOfLastMonth = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH));
set @firstOfMonth = DATE_ADD(@lastOfLastMonth, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
set @today = CURRENT_DATE;
```

#### Today is 2019-10-08 so the output looks like

```
@firstOfLastLastMonth = '2019-08-01'
@lastOfLastLastMonth = '2019-08-31'
@firstOfLastMonth = '2019-09-01'
@lastOfLastMonth = '2019-09-30'
@firstOfMonth = '2019-10-01'
@today = '2019-10-08'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table
where date between 
(date_add (CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL(1 - DAYOFMonth(CURRENT_DATE)) day)) and current_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution for mysql current month and current year, which makes use of indexing properly as well :)

```
-- Current month
SELECT id, timestampfield 
  FROM table1
 WHERE timestampfield >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY)
   AND timestampfield <=  LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE);

-- Current year
SELECT id, timestampfield 
  FROM table1
 WHERE timestampfield >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY)
   AND timestampfield <=  LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE);
```

Comment: And if I want for the week, I just replace DAYOFMONTH with DAYOFWEEK I presume? @Imran

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from <table>
where <dateValue> between last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month + interval 1 day)
                  and curdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

All the responses here have been way too complex. You know that the first of the current month is the current date but with 01 as the date. You can just use YEAR() and MONTH() to build the month date by inputting the NOW() method.
Here's the solution:

```
select * from table_name 
where date between CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR( NOW() ), MONTH( NOW() ), '01') and DATE( NOW() )
```

CONCAT_WS() joins a series of strings with a separator (a dash in this case).
So if today is 2020-08-28, YEAR( NOW() ) = '2020' and MONTH( NOW() ) = '08' and then you just need to append '01' at the end.

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

A less orthodox approach might be

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE LEFT(table_name.date, 7) = LEFT(CURDATE(), 7)
  AND table_name.date <= CURDATE();
```

as a date being between the first of a month and now is equivalent to a date being in this month, and before now. I do feel that this is a bit easier on the eyes than some other approaches, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_sub(current_date(),interval dayofmonth(current_date())-1 day) as first_day_of_month;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this one

```
select DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(now()), INTERVAL  1 MONTH),INTERVAL  1 day) first_day
      ,LAST_DAY(now()) last_day, date(now()) today_day
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some what similar requirement - to `find first day of the month` but based on `year end month` selected by user in their profile page.

Problem statement - find all the `txns` done by the user in his/her financial year. `Financial year` is determined using `year end` month value where `month` can be any valid month - `1 for Jan`, `2 for Feb`, `3 for Mar`,....`12 for Dec`.

For some clients `financial year end`s on `March` and some observe it on `December`.

```
Scenarios - (Today is `08 Aug, 2018`)
   1. If `financial year` ends on `July` then query should return `01 Aug 2018`.
   2. If `financial year` ends on `December` then query should return `01 January 2018`.
   3. If `financial year` ends on `March` then query should return `01 April 2018`.
   4. If `financial year` ends on `September` then query should return `01 October 2017`.
```

And, finally below is the query. -

```
select @date := (case when ? >= month(now()) 
then date_format((subdate(subdate(now(), interval (12 - ? + month(now()) - 1) month), interval day(now()) - 2 day)) ,'%Y-%m-01')
else date_format((subdate(now(), interval month(now()) - ? - 1 month)), '%Y-%m-01') end)
```

where `?` is `year end` month (values from 1 to 12).

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to get the first day of the month. For that, there are several options. In terms of performance, our tests show that there isn't a significant difference between them - [we wrote a whole blog article on the topic](https://kb.zensoft.hu/mysql-get-the-first-day-of-the-month-for-a-given-date/). Our findings show that what really matters is whether you need the result to be VARCHAR, DATETIME, or DATE.

The fastest solution to the real problem of getting the first day of the month returns VARCHAR:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(CURRENT_DATE, 7), '-01') AS first_day_of_month;
```

The second fastest solution gives a DATETIME result - this runs about 3x slower than the previous:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(LEFT(CURRENT_DATE, 7), '-01')) AS first_day_of_month;
```

The slowest solutions return DATE objects. Don't believe me? [Run this SQL Fiddle and see for yourself](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/118188)

In your case, since you need to compare the value with other DATE values in your table, it doesn't really matter what methodology you use because MySQL will do the conversion implicitly even if your formula doesn't return a DATE object.

So really, take your pick. Which is most readable for you? I'd pick the first since it's the shortest and arguably the simplest:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date BETWEEN CONCAT(LEFT(CURRENT_DATE, 7), '-01') AND CURDATE;

SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE(CONCAT(LEFT(CURRENT_DATE, 7), '-01')) AND CURDATE;

SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date BETWEEN (LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURDATE;

SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date BETWEEN (DATE(CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAY) AND CURDATE;

SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date BETWEEN (DATE(CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND CURDATE;

SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'%Y-%m-01') AND CURDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get first date and last date from month and year.**

```
select LAST_DAY(CONCAT(year,'.',month,'.','01')) as registerDate  from user;
   select date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(end_date),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH) AS closingDate from user;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SET @date:='2012-07-11';
SELECT date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(@date),interval 1 DAY), 
       interval -1 MONTH) AS first_day
```