# How do I retrieve data for the previous month in SQL

Tags: mysql

I want to get data for the dates between 2015-05-01 and 2015-06-01 using SQL.
Please help me with the query.

The query I used is:

```
select *,count(id) as multiple_visitors 
    from table1 
    where id=123 
        and (date(server_time) between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 31 DAY) AND CURDATE()) 
    group by user_id having count(id)>1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11808253/4595675

Comment: hard to get it with no information about your database/table structure...

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this with `month()` and `year()`:

```
where month(server_time) = month(curdate() - interval 1 month) and
      year(server_time) = year(curdate() - interval 1 month)
```

However, I recommend a slightly more complex expression:

```
where server_time >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval - day(curdate()) + 1 day), interval 1 month) and
      server_time < date_sub(curdate(), interval - day(curdate()) + 1 day)
```

The advantage is that there are no functions on `server_time`, so the database engine can use an index, if appropriate.

As a note:  the expression `date_sub(curdate(), interval - day(curdate()) + 1 day)` gets midnight on the first day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "`WHERE`" with `MONTH(date)`.

Like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM Table
  WHERE MONTH(date) = 1
```