# COUNT of DISTINCT ids NOT IN subquery?

Tags: mysql

Ok, I'm trying to get a count of users who bought something in a given month but haven't bought something already in any of the previous months (as in, figure out how many new users are there each month), so this is what I'm kinda trying to do but it's obviously not working:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM payment
    WHERE amount > 0
    AND MONTH(payment_date) < "10"
    GROUP BY user_id
) AS new_users_count
FROM payment
WHERE amount > 0
AND MONTH(payment_date) >= "10"
```

If I use "DISTINCT" it returns 0 count.

If I take it out, it returns all the users, new and old.

Plus having a subquery in COUNT() takes a while to process.

Any way this can be done with SUM(IF...)? Or any other more optimal way?

I've looked everywhere for an idea/solution, just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Put the criteria in your WHERE clause. Use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`.

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from payment
where amount > 0
and month(payment_date) >= 10
and user_id not in
(
  select user_id
  from payment
  where amount > 0
  and month(payment_date) < 10
);
```

And here is a alternative with conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select user_id
  from payment
  where amount > 0
  group by user_id
  having sum(month(payment_date) >= 10) > 0
  and sum(month(payment_date) < 10) = 0
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to verify that no payment exists for the same user in the previous month.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tm.USERID)
FROM payment tm
WHERE tm.amount > 0
AND MONTH(tm.payment_date) >= "10"
AND NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 'x' 
    FROM payment lm
    WHERE lm.amount > 0
    AND MONTH(lm.payment_date) < "10"
    AND lm.user_id = tm.user_id
  )
```

PS: Note that this query will not work well anymore once it becomes 2016! Below is a fix for that. It cross joins a calculation to get the first day of the month. This value (DATEPIVOT) is used to get the payment after or before that day. For the calculation, I used the [answer by Aleroot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11808253/511529).

Another advantage of this notation, is that MySQL should be able to better utilize any indexes on payment.payment_date, so as your data grows larger, this query will suffer less from performance decrease.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tm.USERID)
FROM payment tm
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT 
       DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY) as DATEPIVOT) d
WHERE tm.amount > 0
AND tm.payment_date >= d.DATEPIVOT
AND NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 'x' 
    FROM payment lm
    WHERE lm.amount > 0
    AND lm.payment_date < d.DATEPIVOT
    AND lm.user_id = tm.user_id
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id NOT IN (..something..)
```

is understood as

```
COUNT(DISTINCT (user_id NOT IN (..something..))
```

and `NOT IN` is a boolean operator returning true/false (=1/0)

The condition does not make sense in the `COUNT()` - you probably wanted to do it in the `WHERE` clause. Or you might use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`.

But not using subquery at all is usually better (MySQL 5.6+ can handle subqueries well, but yours is "dependent" one). Something like this should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p1.user_id)
FROM payment p1
LEFT JOIN payment p2
  ON p1.user_id = p2.user_id
     AND p2.amount > 0
     AND MONTH(p2.payment_date) < 10
WHERE p1.amount > 0
  AND MONTH(p1.payment_date) >= 10
  AND p2.user_id IS NULL;
```

The left join will join any existing row for the same user_id which ordered something "before", so you just check with `p2.user_id IS NULL` that no such "previous order" exists for this user_id. Then you count the results - as each user can be returned multiple times depending on the number of payments, the `DISTINCT` takes care of that.

Some notes

- `MONTH(datetime)` returns number so I removed the quotes around `10`
- you need an index on `user_id` to make it work in any reasonable time and preferably composite index on `(user_id, amount, payment_date)` to turn it into and index scan for the join
- unfortunately `MONTH(p1.payment_date) >= 10` is not an indexable condition and moreover it will change in effect next year, so you should probably use full date in the comparison, like `p1.payment_date >= '2015-10-01'` (and the same for `p2`) and then add an index on `(payment_date, user_id, amount)` to make the `FROM` part fast too (only users having at least "new" payment will be checked, old users with no activity will not be rechecked all the time).

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but why don't you use the DISTINCT after the SELECT?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  COUNT(user_id NOT IN
```

Comment: This will only do the "distinct filtering" after everything is counted, so it will return only one number which is unique by definition.