# Get 1 year old data from begining of month

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get 1 year old data from database till current date but from the beginning of month.if today is 25-08-2016 i have to get data from 01-08-2015 till now

Comment: It helps to post code that you've tried.

Comment: Please profide a [mcve]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808232/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-current-month  (- interval 1 year)

Comment: `select * 
from table
where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);`

Comment: If i am logging in on 28-08-2016, i should get data from 01-08-2015 to 28-08-2016

Answer (score 0):

First find first day of the month link
`$firstDateOfMonthLastYear = date('01-m-Y', strtotime('-1 years');`

`$today = date('d-m-Y');`

Run Below query to get all data as per your requirement.

`$query = "SELECT * from tbname where reportDate between ".$firstDateOfMonthLastYear." and ".$today." order by tbname.primary_key desc"`

You need to replace tbname by your original table name.
You need to replace tbname.primary_key by your table primary key.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter try this

```html
$where = "date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)";
$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: I got the answer
->where('admit_date >= CONCAT(LEFT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR,7),"-01")')