# Date Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm looking to setup a calendar date stored procedure in Mysql. The purpose is to be able to select the first day and last day of a given month by call the procedure.  I know it is probably a very simple thing that I am missing. Below is what I have tried.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CalendarDate
        @startdate DATE,
        @enddate DATE
    AS
SELECT
    (SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH)) AS startdate
,   (SELECT LAST_DAY(CURDATE())) AS enddate
;
```

I would like to use the above to be able run a query by just saying:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE action_date BETWEEN @startdate AND @ endate
```

Comment: For MySQL - this procedure code is synthactically wrong.

Comment: I'm slightly baffled - you CALL a stored procedure - you cannot use an sp in a select

Comment: Assuming you'd execute SP then use variables values assigned in your query - SP and query MUST be executed in the same connection (and without reconnection between statements!).

Comment: I see nothing 'procedural' about this problem

Comment: Please look answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808232/how-do-i-select-between-the-1st-day-of-the-current-month-and-current-day-in-mysq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select between the 1st day of the current month and current day in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808232/how-do-i-select-between-the-1st-day-of-the-current-month-and-current-day-in-mysq)