# Get records of current month

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, timestamp

How can I select Current Month records from a table of MySql database??

Like now current month is January. I would like to get records of January Month, Where data type of my table column is `timestamp`.I would like to know the sql query.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500527/select-current-months-records-mysql-from-timestamp-column

Answer (score 204, accepted):

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(columnName) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(columnName) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: This is not quite correct. If I have records with `2015-12-25` and `2016-12-30` they will both be selected, which I don't think is the expected behavior. Instead try the solution by @saharsh-shah below.

Comment: Bad: Will calculate the `MONTH()` for each row. Better try a range comparison on the column.

Comment: @Sebastian Please, provide an answer

Comment: The question is marked as duplicated, see the linked questions. New answers can't be added. You should go for something like `columnName > "2017-11-01 00:00:00"`.

Comment: @Pila's comment was accurate at the time, but the answer has since been updated for the query to result in the correct functionality.

Comment: For postgre people you just need date_trunc like SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE date_trunc('month',columnName) = date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE)

Answer (score 41):

Check the [**MySQL Datetime**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) Functions:

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE YEAR(columnName) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND 
      MONTH(columnName) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE());
```

Comment: Bad: Will calculate the `MONTH()` for each row. Better try a range comparison on the column.

Comment: @Sebastian Please, provide an answer

Comment: @Sebastian why not provide an answer?

Comment: There are two duplicates linked at the top of the page. Both provide good answers. Why should I add another one? Anyway: Adding answers to duplicate questions isn't possible.

Comment: select * from t.stuff where date between DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-01") and LAST_DAY(NOW());

Comment: @Sebastian I am a newbie for SQL. Will you please explain how is this a bad answer? What is meant by Will calculate the MONTH() for each row. Better try a range comparison on the column

Comment: MySQL will walk through the table and calculate MONTH(x) for each row, then check if it's today. @Martian2049's example will allow using an index or at least avoid calculation MONTH() on each row. Imagine a 1.200.000 rows table starting  ten yrs. ago: Using an index and no MONTH() will reduce the amount to check to 100k instead if 1,2M.

Answer (score 4):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(columnName))= MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Comment: Bad: Will calculate the `MONTH()` for each row. Better try a range comparison on the column.

Comment: @Sebastian Please, provide an answer