# select only year and month in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I have this value in my database ***101101-2017-06-000***
It is value for column `lddap_no` I want to select value with year equal to current year and current month my query is

`SELECT lddap_no FROM lddap WHERE YEAR(lddap_no) = '2017'  AND MONTH(lddap_no) = '06'   ORDER BY sys_id  DESC LIMIT 1`

I used YEAR() and MONTH() respectively but it didnt work I get no result even if I have one entry.

How to correctly compare year and month from a column value that is not formatted date.

`UPDATE`

Used `WHERE YEAR(substring(lddap_no,7,10)) = '2017'  AND MONTH(substring(lddap_no,12,13)) = '06'` Still same no result found

tried using this

```
WHERE YEAR(SUBSTRING(CAST(lddap_no AS VARCHAR(100)), 7, 10)) = '2017'  AND MONTH(SUBSTRING(CAST(lddap_no AS VARCHAR(100)), 12, 13)) = '06'
```

Comment: mysql is what i am using but i also want to know in sql i think they are the same anyway

Comment: Use substring for extracting year and month

Comment: Year is only for extractinng the year value of a date

Comment: Your value is not a date or datetime value so the functions MONTH and YEAR will not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get records of current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276975/get-records-of-current-month)

Comment: i tried to use **WHERE YEAR(substring(lddap_no,7,10)) = '2017'  AND MONTH(substring(lddap_no,12,13)) = '06'** stil same result what is wrong in my where clause

Comment: Do you mean *ldap*? Or is it a custom format? I suppose it's better to store a real date in a real date field. So it's easy to select date based data.

Comment: no it is a column in database . its value is `101101-2017-06-000` which is not a date format that is why it didnt work. I believe this is not a duplicate of the one mentioned above @schellingerht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an XY problem. The real problem here is that you are storing your data in the wrong format. Store dates as dates or datetimes, then you can start querying using the MySQL date functions.

In the meantime since it's a varchar, for a cheap hack, you could try a LIKE clause:

`......WHERE ldap_no LIKE "%-2017-06-%"`

Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try :

```
SELECT * FROM lddap WHERE lddap_no LIKE '%2017-06%';
```