# MySQL: The right way to calculate MTD

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep seeing answers like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21277074/4236404 being the default accepted answer for how to get the Month to date rows in a MySQL query.

The current answer(s):

```
SELECT id, created
  FROM table1
 WHERE MONTH(created) = MONTH(CURDATE())
   AND YEAR(created) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

This query will work, but it's inefficient and MySQL will perform a full scan to get the results.

Therefore the correct way to get the rows for a Month to Date (MTD) query is as follows (I will use PDO and PHP to demonstrate:

```
//get the first day of the month
$month_first_day = date( "Y-m-01" );

//select the record where the created date is equal to or bigger than the first day of the current month.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, created FROM table1 WHERE created >= :first_day_of_month');
$stmt->bindParam(':first_day_of_month', $month_first_day);
$stmt->execute();
$realm_data = $stmt->fetch();
```

Bonus queries:

To get all records for today do the following:

```
$today = date( "Y-m-d" );
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, created FROM table1 WHERE created >= :today');
$stmt->bindParam(':today', $today);
$stmt->execute();
$realm_data = $stmt->fetch();
```

To get all the records for yesterday do the following:

```
$today = date( "Y-m-d" );
$yesterday = date( "Y-m-d", time()-86400 );
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, created FROM table1 WHERE created >= :yesterday AND created < :today');
$stmt->bindParam(':today', $today);
$stmt->bindParam(':yesterday', $yesterday);
$stmt->execute();
$realm_data = $stmt->fetch();
```

To get all the records for the last 7 days do the following:

```
$seven_days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, created FROM table1 WHERE created >= :seven_days_ago');
$stmt->bindParam(':seven_days_ago', $seven_days_ago);
$stmt->execute();
$realm_data = $stmt->fetch();
```

Assumptions/Tip:

The column in MySQL is set to the datetime format.

Comment: normative pattern for filtering rows based on date or datetime range is for the table to have a column of datatype DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP; and then compare that to the beginning of range and end of range values. e.g. `WHERE t.mydtcol >= '2019-02-01' AND t.mydtcol < '2019-02-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH.`  We can use an expression in place of the literals, e.g. `WHERE t.mydtcol >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND t.mydtcol < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

Comment: pretty sure  this `LIKE
  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(<datetime>), '%Y-%m'), "%") ` atleast it will on DATETIME and can use indexes... I saw your answer basicallyyou want to avoid using a function on the left side off anny operator or keyword like `IN` or `LIKE`

Comment: Sjoe, a lot of downvotes for a tutorial attempt to help others, do people not see my answer and explanation below?

Comment: Well if you want to write a tutorial for new programmers for writing efficient queries shouldn't you obvious know how to do it it yourself??

Comment: I don't understand, I wrote the post below and then stackoverflow said I need to put an answer as well. Let me delete the current OP and post my answer there instead

Comment: "I wrote the post below and then stackoverflow said I need to put an answer as well. Let me delete the current OP and post my answer there instead" iám pretty use you have [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54834533/edit) rights on your own question..

Comment: I meant to edit, done.

Comment: i posted a answer on how you possible can use `WHERE MONTH(created) = MONTH(CURDATE())
   AND YEAR(created) = YEAR(CURDATE())` and efficient atleast with MySQL 5.7+

Comment: That is not efficient.

Comment: That is not efficient" explain why?? You sure you know how the MySQL optimizer works and uses indexes in combination with [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/generated-column-index-optimizations.html)? Or how the MySQL optimizer works in general when calculating cost based?

Comment: @ErikThiart - the downvotes are because you have posted no question. You posted an answer, as a question. Yet, you also included a link to some other question that you're apparently responding to (which, in turn, is a duplicate of *another* question). You should have posted your answer to the original question that you posted a link to. Posting your answer here, as a question (with repeated content as an answer) is not valid.

Comment: I had a question, got the down votes and then edited the question to be the answer instead

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not allow creating expression/functions based indexes there is a workaround which is possible from MySQL 5.7+ with [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) which can be indexed. 
Makes sure to make the tables as InnoDB which can make indexes on non stored generated columns.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
 d DATETIME 
 , dy INT AS (YEAR(d)) 
 , dm INT AS (MONTH(d))
 , INDEX(dy, dm)                    
) Engine = InnoDB ;
```

**Explain**

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 t
WHERE
    MONTH(d) = MONTH(CURDATE())
  AND
    YEAR(d) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

**Result**

```
| id  | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra       |
| --- | ----------- | ----- | ---------- | ---- | ------------- | --- | ------- | --- | ---- | -------- | ----------- |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | t     |            | ALL  | dy            |     |         |     | 19   | 78.95    | Using where |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pmiJVKnj4nByoC7yitSq6V/0)

Yes i know it says `ALL` but MySQL is right here. the result returned 15 records the table is 19 records.

Also you need to know the rows output in the explain output is a expected number off record for the InnoDB engine it's not the actual number.

But 15 times a random disk I.O (6ms * 15) and stream it is (alot) more expensive then a full table scan which does one random disk I.O (6ms * 1) and can stream the data in one go.

MySQL's optimizer/execution is costs based which calculates relative costs based on random disk I/O which are the most expensive.

But notice it said possible key `dy` MySQL knows it can use the index now for

`WHERE
        MONTH(d) = MONTH(CURDATE())
      AND
        YEAR(d) = YEAR(CURDATE())`

Only MySQL was thinking iám not going to do more work by reading the index.

Still waiting until MySQL supports expression/functional indexes  maybe they add in later a MySQL 8 version. 
 
MySQL 8 is still worked on and getting updates.

`CREATE INDEX index_name ON table (YEAR(d));`

But i think it will not happen that soon, MySQL does support it more or less with the workaround i used so it don't think they are in a hurry to implement it..

MySQL before MySQL 8.0.16 also didn't support CHECK CONSTRAINTS they also didn't had a hurry to implement it because MySQL already supported it more or less with a VIEW with a [CHECK OPTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-check-option.html) to give a good example.

**Edit:**

Seams i was speaking to soon that MySQL wouldn't support that feature expression/functional indexes soon.

i noticed MySQL 8.0.13 update added expression/functional indexes.

**Functional Key Parts**

> A “normal” index indexes column values or prefixes of column values.
>   For example, in the following table, the index entry for a given t1
>   row includes the full col1 value and a prefix of the col2 value
>   consisting of its first 10 characters:
>
> MySQL 8.0.13 and higher supports functional key parts that index
>   expression values rather than column or column prefix values. Use of
>   functional key parts enables indexing of values not stored directly in
>   the table. Examples:
>
> `CREATE TABLE t1 (col1 INT, col2 INT, INDEX func_index ((ABS(col1))));
>   CREATE INDEX idx1 ON t1 ((col1 + col2)); CREATE INDEX idx2 ON t1
>   ((col1 + col2), (col1 - col2), col1); ALTER TABLE t1 ADD INDEX ((col1
>   * 40) DESC);`

see [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html)

In MySQL 8.0.13+ you can do

`CREATE INDEX index_name ON table (YEAR(created), MONTH(created));`

Comment: @ErikThiart see update MySQL 8.0.13+ seams already to be supporting expression/functional indexes