# Show total row from current month

Tags: php, mysql

I need to show total count of rows from database ordering by month.

There are my code:

```
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT aptName FROM property WHERE status='Sold' GROUP BY MONTH(createdate)";
 if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 printf("%d\n",$rowcount);
 mysqli_free_result($result);
 }
 ?>
```

I want to show how many properties sold out in current month. Same thing in next month and so on..

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276975/get-records-of-current-month) it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL you could try the following query:

```
 SELECT count(*) tot_apt_in_month
     FROM property 
     WHERE status='Sold' 
     AND MONTH(createdate) = month(curdate())
```

To see the result you should at least `echo` the row content:

```
  while($row = $result->fetch_array())
  {
  echo $row['tot_apt_in_month'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

or

```
     "SELECT MONTH(createdate) my_month, count(*) tot_apt_in_month
     FROM property 
     WHERE status='Sold' 
     AND MONTH(createdate) = month(durdate())
     GROUP BY MONTH(createdate)
     ";

  while($row = $result->fetch_array())
  {
      echo $row['my_month'] . " " . $row['tot_apt_in_month'];
      echo "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: answer  updated ..  you should add the code for echo the rows content

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query which will return you multiple records with month and sold property count.

```
SELECT count(id) soldPropertyCount, MONTHNAME(createdate)
FROM property WHERE status='Sold' GROUP BY MONTH(createdate)
```

Hope it helps you!!