# How to get number of new records from database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have table that has column that stores `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. 
I am using PHP code to show:

1. Records Enter Today
2. Records entered this month

Any idea?

Comment: For month record use Mysql month function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need appropriate ways of saying

```
 WHERE record_timestamp >= something
```

In the case of "today"  `something` should be `CURDATE()`.  That returns all records timestamped after midnight today.

In the case of "this month" `something` should be

```
 DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

That chooses midnight of the first day of the present month.

Taking it a little further, you get "yesterday" like this:

```
 WHERE record_timestamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND record_timestamp <  CURDATE()
```

You get "last month" like this:

```
WHERE record_timestamp >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  AND record_timestamp  < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

A detail:  Because you're using the `TIMESTAMP` data type, all these computations will be performed using the current time zone setting of your connection to the MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

You can get records as like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateColumn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);        
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateColumn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply query like:

- To get today enter record.

  ```
  select * from table where DATE( from_unixtime( date_column )) = '2016-01-06';
  ```
- To get particular month record.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH( from_unixtime( date_column )) = month_no;
  ```

Comment: The WHERE query you suggest is not sargable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Answer (score 0):

To get today's records:-

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date_format(`created`,'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE();
```

To find current month record follow :-

[Select current months records mysql from timestamp column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500527/select-current-months-records-mysql-from-timestamp-column)

Comment: The WHERE query you suggest is not sargable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the records entered today, then take today's date & append time to it as 00:00:00, then calculate the timestamp of it and store it in variable $start, similarly calculate $end by appending time as 24:00:00  & in sql pass where clause with condition date >= $start and date <= $end.

Same logic you can apply by getting month's 1st date time stamp and month's end date time stamp.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Complete PHP code using the function **num_rows** as it says [here](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

---

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
$results = $conn -> query($SQL);
if($results -> num_rows > 0){
     $noOfResults = $results -> num_rows;
}
else{
     $noOfResults = 0;
}
echo $noOfResults;
```

If you want the results from the last month just use INTERVAL 1 MONTH instead of 1 DAY, as @devpro answer states.

Comment: Sorry, this is an antipattern. If you want a count of records, you should `SELECT COUNT(*)` rather than burdening your network with all the data, just to count and discard it in your PHP client.

Comment: @OllieJones Naveed said that he wants the number of rows and he also wants to show the records and that's what my code is doing. $results variable stores implicitly the data.