# MySQL Select rows of Current Month for an ID & Show in HTML tables by ASC/DESC order

Tags: php, html, mysql

Successfully connected to database.

I have a table named "meal" and I am using a code like,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT date, month, day, breakfast, launch, dinner, meal_total, note FROM meal WHERE stid='$_SESSION[stid]'  AND  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 35) sub ORDER BY date DESC";

$result = $dbconnection->query($sql);
```

I am selecting the rows by, `stid='$_SESSION[stid]'`.
The "`date`" column records "`current timestamp`".

I am using this code to show the values of rows in a HTML table like,

```
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<table >
<tr>
    <th>Timestamp</th>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Breakfast</th>
    <th>Launch</th>
    <th>Dinner</th>
    <th>Total Meals</th>
</tr>";

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row["date"]. "</td>
<td>" . $row["month"]. " </td>
<td>" . $row["day"]. "</td>
<td>" . $row["breakfast"]. "</td>
<td>" . $row["launch"]. "</td>
<td>" . $row["dinner"]. "</td>
<td>" . $row["meal_total"]. "</td>
</tr>";

         }
         echo "</table>";
    } else {
         echo "No results!";
    }
```

The code is returning all the rows of the User (as ID). Like,

```
        __________________________________________________________
        Year-Month-Date TIME | Nov 2015 | 10 | Others Details ...| 
         _________________________________________________________
        Year-Month-Date TIME | Nov 2015 | 02 | Others Details ...| 
        __________________________________________________________
        Year-Month-Date TIME | Oct 2015 | 15 | Others Details ...| 
        __________________________________________________________
```

But the problem is I need to show only the rows from current month. Like,

```
            _________________________________________________________
            Year-Month-Date TIME | Nov 2015 | 10 | Others Details ...| 
            __________________________________________________________
            Year-Month-Date TIME | Nov 2015 | 02 | Others Details ...| 
            __________________________________________________________
```

Please help me sir. I know there will be a simple trick when selecting rows from my table but I have failed to reveal one as my need. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4655009/1745672

Comment: @rahat : you got answer or not ?

Comment: @Nana : I have got some suggestions but not succeed yet. I am trying to.

Comment: @Nana : Sir, I have tried like that, 

$month = date("M Y"); and, SQL part like, WHERE  stid='$_SESSION[stid]'  AND month='$month' . Please help me by an example. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, `$_SESSION[stid]` is wrong. It should be `$_SESSION['stid']` @RahatVuban

Comment: Sir, $_SESSION[stid] , is working well!  My problem is to select rows from current month & echo the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a date comparison condition in your `SQL`:

```
SELECT date, month, day, breakfast, launch, dinner, meal_total, note 
FROM   meal 
WHERE  stid='$_SESSION[stid]'  
AND    date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -DAY(CURDATE())+1 DAY)    
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 35
```

Tested in this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bbfe/20).

The `DATE_ADD` function is used here to return the first day of the current month.

Note that the `SQL` you provided has a syntax error: the sequence `AND  ORDER BY` is invalid.

Also, you wrap an inner query inside an outer query that adds nothing to what the inner already does. Just keep the inner one.

Comment: Oh yes! there is a syntax error. Now I am trying to implement your suggestion. I have a further question. If I want to select Rows from Last Month what will be the code then? - Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rahat, you should now look and read about [`DATE_ADD`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) and learn how to do it yourself. If you consider your **original** question answered, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry Sir, Unfortunately the code,

AND    date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE -DAY(date)+1 DAY)

Returns me no result/output!

Comment: If I look at the output you have given in your question, it seems like your date column has values like `Year-Month-Date TIME`, but that is evidently not a date. And as a consequence, there is no result when comparing it with real dates. I also wonder what those `month` and `day` columns are for, when you have a date column that is supposed to have all a date is about.

Comment: My Actual "date" format is like : 2015-11-07 13:12:01
And, "month" format is like : Nov 2015

Comment: Don't run the query. FIrst echo the query. Get output of that query and run in sql of your database to check what exactly it comes. @RahatVuban

Comment: @trincot : Actually I am taking all the values from a html input form. The first "date" column is for recording submission time. The "month" & the "day" column is for user choice.

Comment: OK, I have corrected a mistake in the SQL in my answer.

Comment: @trincot : Sir, This time I am getting all the rows of all months. I think there may be a mistake in my code started from here : 

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<table >

Comment: No, the PHP code is not going to produce rows that it did not get from the database. Give an example date that you get in the result, that you did not want to have.

Comment: @trincot : Sir. Thanks a lot. At last I have succeed! Actually there is a simple mistake of mine. And your Last Edit is working perfectly for me.

Comment: @NanaPartykar : Thank you too Sir. Best wishes.